# ¿Cómo descargar un archivo de Drive sin login?

Tags: php, google-drive

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en PHP para descargar archivos de Google Drive desde PHP, cuando utilizo:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$fileId.'?alt=media&access_token='.$access_token
```

Funciona bien pero para archivos pesados, ya que no devuelve el nombre del archivo.

Pero cuando utilizo:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='.$fileId
```

Me redirecciona a la página de inicio de sesión de Drive, una vez logueados ya deja descargar pero necesito que cualquier persona sin registro pueda descargar.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No se deben incluir cosas como "espero puedan ayudarme" ni "gracias de antemano", se debe incluir sólo lo que sea necesario para que la pregunta sea clara. ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 1):

Para que cualquiera pueda descargar un archivo de Google Drive sin que se tenga que autenticarse al usar un enlace con el patrón  `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='.$fileId` el archivo deberá estar compartido con cualquiera que tenga el enlace.